# Adding billing_phone to sales_order_invoice_grid.xml in magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2.3.2

I was trying to add billing phone to sales_order_invoice_grid.xml.how to do that. i added this code in app\code\Magento\Sales\view\adminhtml\ui_component\sales_order_invoice_grid.xml.

```
<column name="telephone">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Phone Number</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">6</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

app\code\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\Grid\Collection.php

```
namespace Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface as FetchStrategy;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface as EntityFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface as EventManager;
use Magento\Sales\Ui\Component\DataProvider\Document;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected $document = Document::class;
    
    /**
     * Initialize dependencies.
     *
     * @param EntityFactory $entityFactory
     * @param Logger $logger
     * @param FetchStrategy $fetchStrategy
     * @param EventManager $eventManager
     * @param string $mainTable
     * @param string $resourceModel
     */
    public function __construct(
        EntityFactory $entityFactory,
        Logger $logger,
        FetchStrategy $fetchStrategy,
        EventManager $eventManager,
        $mainTable = 'sales_invoice_grid',
        $resourceModel = \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice::class
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $mainTable, $resourceModel);
    }
     protected function _renderFiltersBefore()
    {
    $joinTable = $this->getTable('sales_order_address');
    $this->getSelect()->joinLeft($joinTable, "main_table.entity_id = 
    {$joinTable}.parent_id AND {$joinTable}.address_type = 'billing'", 
      ['telephone']);
       parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
   }
}
```

but phone fields are wrong.how to correct it
how to take value from database. can anyone show the exact file and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $this->getSelect()->joinLeft($joinTable, "main_table.entity_id = 
    {$joinTable}.parent_id AND {$joinTable}.address_type = 'billing'", 
      ['telephone']);
       parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
   }
```

**it should be**

```
 $this->getSelect()->joinLeft($joinTable, "main_table.order_id = 
    {$joinTable}.parent_id AND {$joinTable}.address_type = 'billing'", 
      ['telephone']);
       parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
   }
```

You are  relation ship field is  `sales_invoice_grid` table `order_id` with `sales_order_address` table `parent_id`

Comment: how we can use 'main_table'  .what does it mean?can you explain

Comment: How to disaply City, State, Country in sales_invoice_grid section .can you help

Comment: magento 2 put alias name main_table when a collection query run  that why you can use

Comment: use `['telephone','city','region']` instead of `['telephone'] `

Comment: How to show products ordered along with that? can you pls help me

Answer (score 0):

I added phone in order grid .hope this helps you..

First you need to add column through uicomponent

> app\code\Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\ui_component\sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<columns name="sales_order_columns">
    <column name="telephone">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Phone Number</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">6</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
 </columns>
 </listing>
```

then Add the collection file in your module

```
Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection.php

<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid;

use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection as OriginalCollection;

/**
 * Order grid extended collection
 */
class Collection extends OriginalCollection
{

    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        $this->addFilterToMap('status', 'main_table.status');
        $this->addFilterToMap('customer_id', 'main_table.customer_id');

        parent::_initSelect();
    }

    protected function _renderFiltersBefore()
    {
    $joinTable = $this->getTable('sales_order_address');
    $this->getSelect()->joinLeft($joinTable, "main_table.entity_id = 
    {$joinTable}.parent_id AND {$joinTable}.address_type = 'billing'", 
      ['telephone']);
       parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
   }
    
}
```

At last Add di.xml in your module

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
 <arguments>
 <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
 <item name="sales_order_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection</item>
 </argument>
 </arguments>
 </type>
</config>
```

It will add customer billing phone number in order grid with filter. I wrote this code it is my tested code. I hope this will help

mark as solution if helps you

Comment: i want to add it in invoice grid.can you show me the code.

Answer (score 0):

try below code

> app\code\Magento\Sales\view\adminhtml\ui_component\sales_order_invoice_grid.xml.

```
<column name="telephone">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Phone Number</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">6</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

> app\code\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\Grid\Collection.php

```
namespace Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface as FetchStrategy;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface as EntityFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface as EventManager;
use Magento\Sales\Ui\Component\DataProvider\Document;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected $document = Document::class;
    
    /**
     * Initialize dependencies.
     *
     * @param EntityFactory $entityFactory
     * @param Logger $logger
     * @param FetchStrategy $fetchStrategy
     * @param EventManager $eventManager
     * @param string $mainTable
     * @param string $resourceModel
     */
    public function __construct(
        EntityFactory $entityFactory,
        Logger $logger,
        FetchStrategy $fetchStrategy,
        EventManager $eventManager,
        $mainTable = 'sales_invoice_grid',
        $resourceModel = \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice::class
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $mainTable, $resourceModel);
    }
     protected function _renderFiltersBefore()
    {
    $joinTable = $this->getTable('sales_order_address');
    $this->getSelect()->joinLeft($joinTable, "main_table.order_id = 
    {
      $joinTable}.parent_id AND {$joinTable}.address_type = 'billing'", 
      ['telephone']);
       parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
   }
}
```